# What is the difference among const int *&a, int const *&a, int* const &a and int*& const a?

Tags: c++, constants

Is there a set of rules that helps us understand the definition of variables with different order of declarators and keywords ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: Please read https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness